# ContextErrorException in DebugClassLoader.php line 241

Tags: php, symfony

I am always having this error at DebugClassLoader.php line 241. Debugged many times and each time the class name is different. Sometimes it is empty and sometimes it contains some junk characters.

I have changed the PHP version and also checked the cache system. No caching is enabled in the dev environment. Also I checked the normal and optimized composer class maps with no success

Restarting Apache fix the issue temporarily but re-appears in any request after that. Any idea?

[image]g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found out that this is an issue with PHP 7 running on Windows.

Just posting this as answer just in case anybody came across with the same issue. I have switched to Vagrant

Reference - [Bug #74015     ReflectionClass::getInterfaceNames wrong entry with random memory location](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74015)

Answer (score 0):

It took me an hour to resolve this issue.
If You are running apache server on windows (maybe xampp or other engine) and done some changes with classes, or routes and error still persist check 2 things.
First thing -> just reboot apache (stop and start again from xampp menu)
If problem is solved, gr8. If still persist check /web/app.php/ version of website (prod env), clear the cache: `php bin/console cache:clear -e prod --no-warmup`

It was working for  me like this before debug:
Dev enviroment was going crazy, Prod enviroment went nice and smooth. Issue was about php on windows apache's class cache